# Has a British political party ever had more women MPs than men before The Independent Group?

Tags: united-kingdom, parties, parliament, gender

> "The Independent Group instantly has a majority of female MPs"
>   [Esther Webber](https://twitter.com/estwebber/status/1098178235580465152),

Other than where the group of MPs is a single person (such as Caroline Lucas), has a party ever had more women MPs than men MPs before?

Comment: Technically the Independent Group is not a political party. It receives funding from a private company called Gemini owned by Gavin Shuker, doesn't have to disclose it's financial donors or backers and has no leader.

Answer (score 5):

No, at no point has a party with more than a single MP had a majority of female MPs.  (As of this writing, The Independent Group is not a political party.)

Labour has so far been closest, with 45% of its MPs elected at the 2017 election being female ([Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Women_in_the_House_of_Commons_of_the_United_Kingdom#Current_representation)).

Comment: Second place being tied between Plaid Cymru (2017) at 25% and the Independent Liberals (1935) at 25%

Comment: @Valorum: I thought the SNP is 33% (16/48) women MPs? [TheGuardian, 12/2019](https://www.theguardian.com/politics/2019/dec/13/uk-elects-record-number-of-female-mps)

Comment: Would you mind if I edited your answer with the new information from your deleted one?

Comment: The reason I deleted it is because I subsequently spotted in the headline "before The Independent Group", and the 2019 election was not before The Independent Group.  So it doesn't actually answer the question.